# Prob for defining a style with css

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a little issue with styling my asp.net page :

in the top of the my aspx page I declared :

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS3 Menu - Impressionist UI - by Valeriu Timbuc for Design Modo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body { margin: 5px; background: #f2f2f2 no-repeat top center; }
        ul.menu { margin: 5px auto 0 auto; }
    </style>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>
```

In some place I have this code :

```
<div class="rounded-corners"; style=" margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; ">  
    <asp:GridView id="MyGridView"        
     DataSourceID="MyDataSource1" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     GridLines="Both"
     AllowSorting="True" 
     AllowPaging="True" 
     CssClass="mGrid"
     PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"

     Runat="Server" PageSize="35">         

       <columns>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="FICHIER"
            readonly="true"     
            headertext="Fichier"
            ItemStyle-CssClass="CellFile">                
          </asp:boundfield>
```

In this latter I tried to use the `ItemStyle-CssClass="CellFile"` in irder to define a padding-left and a color. So in my css file I Have :

`/* Reset */
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

/* Menu */
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 468px;

    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: #4c4e5a;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    top: 3px;
    left: -2px;
}

/* Links */

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    background: #1f2024;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 205px;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 125px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:inherit;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

/* Icons */

.menu a.documents { background: url(../img/docs.png) no-repeat 0px center; width: 125px;}
.menu a.messages { background: url(../img/bubble.png) no-repeat 0px center; width: 125px;}
.menu a.signout { background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 0px center; width: 125px;}

.mGrid { 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0; 
    border: solid 1px #525252; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.mGrid td { 
    padding: 2px; 
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; 
    color: #717171; 
}
.mGrid th  
{

    /*padding: 4px 2px; */
    color: #fff; 
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: #424242 url(../img/grd_head.png) repeat-x top; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: #4c4e5a;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    text-align : left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family:  Cambria;

}
.mGrid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(../img/grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }
.mGrid .pgr { border: 1px solid #424242; background: #424242 url(../img/grd_pgr.png) repeat-x top; }
.mGrid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0; }
.mGrid .pgr td { 
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 0 6px; 
    border-left: solid 1px #666; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #fff; 
    line-height: 12px; 
 }   
.mGrid .pgr a  
{
    color: #58ae1b; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: #424242 url(../img/grd_head.png) repeat-x top; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: #4c4e5a;
}
.mGrid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }

 .rnd1 {
   background-color: #f0ff00;
   height: 1px;
 }
 .gv1 {
   width: 100%;
   border: 0px none;
 }
 .gv1 th {
   background-color: #C1C4D0;
 }

 .rounded-corners {
  border: 1px solid #424242;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: #424242;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #424242 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #424242 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #424242 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #424242 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: #424242;
}
.CellFile
{
   padding-left:100px; 
   color:Aqua; 
}`

So When I Run the style won't apply but when I delete the `<head></head>` part the style works fine. I m new to css and asp.net and I guess the prob is somewhere in the styling declaration. How could I make it Work ?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a `;` after class attribute `class="rounded-corners";`

Comment: what does the rendered html look like?

Comment: The rendered page is : 
http://hpics.li/26adf5c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does it make a difference if you make it a self-closing tag?

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="CellFile" />
```

if not, you might have to make it a template field.